# Cannot create table in odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I just created a new module with the following structure:

````
mainfolder

-models

--__init__.py

`from . import student`

--student.py

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class SchoolStudent(models.Model):
    _name = "school.student"
    _description = "School Student Patient"

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    age = fields.Char(string='Age')
    gender = fields.Selection([
        ('male', 'Male'),
        ('female', 'Female'),
        ('other', 'Other'),
    ], required=True, default='male')
    note = fields.Text(string='Description')
```
-__init__.py

`from . import models`

-__manifest__.py
````

The problem is, when I installed  the module, I cannot find the table "School student" in my database, I updated the module several times but the same.

How to fix this issue please?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you write xml views?

Comment: You should have views folder inside your main folder like models you're having.

Comment: What does that have to do with the database table not existing @Saks_here ?

Comment: @Hicham are you sure the module/apps installs correctely? Watch out for some hints in the Odoo server log to find out.

Comment: @czoellner kindly bear with my explanation. I was about to say, views are important to display the records of table to the users. But hicham doesn't give his views structure in his post. That's why commented out.

Comment: @hicham, have you defined access rights to the class you created? Kindly do respond when someone about to help you.

Comment: Hi Saks_here, Sorry but I already posted an answer!
I have not yet defined access rights to the class!
do I need to do it at this point, because at the moment I want the module to just create the table with the fields defined.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I inform you that I solved the problem just by creating the view and access rights for the module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Odoo15 - For someone who still got this issue:

In my case, i'm missing code in my root `__init__.py`

My custom module named `school` and saved inside `/var/www/html/odoo_15/addons/school`

So the root init file should have path like `/var/www/html/odoo_15/addons/school/__init__.py`  and the content should be

`from . import models`